# Chrome Extension Id

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm working with an extension for chrome, and I'm supposed to use the Id of the extension.

I'm able to get the Id from the developer mode (it's an unpackaged extension).
So my doubts are:

When I publish the extension on the chrome extension store everyone will have a different Id?

If yes, how could I access it via code? (react.js)

Comment: The id will be constant once you upload it to the web store, it's `chrome.runtime.id`

Comment: Thanks I missed the reference on the article I was reading, this helped me to read it again.